# ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am upgrading from Rails 5.2 to Rails 7. After running the server with rails s when I go to any routes, it gives me Completed 500 Internal Server Error

**3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sprockets/4.2.0/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:24:in `resolve': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)**

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'eye-candy', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'charts', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:93:in `track'

line 93: yield in track method

```
def track
  _start_track_time = Time.now
  _failed           = true
  _timeout          = true
  begin
    yield
    _failed = false
  rescue => e
    # does not execute on timeouts
    _timeout = false
    raise e
  ensure
  end
end

[Rollbar] Scheduling item
[Rollbar] Sending item
[Rollbar] Sending json
[Rollbar] Got unexpected status code from Rollbar api: 429
[Rollbar] Response: {
"err": 1,
"message": "Over free plan monthly limit. Project id <> access 
token <>."
}
[Rollbar] Details: https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=<> 
(only available if report was successful)
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):

16:       <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap|Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
17:     <% end %>
18: 
19:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
20:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'eye-candy', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
21:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'charts', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
22:     <% if %w(connect.juvo juvo.sasa.solutions).include?(request.host) %>


app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:93:in `track'
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-08-26 17:00:01 +0530
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (3.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 18 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[36mNote Load (1.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT `notes`.* FROM `notes` WHERE `notes`.`controller` = 'welcome' AND `notes`.`action` = 'index' AND `notes`.`note_type` = 'documentation' AND (length(body)>0) ORDER BY `notes`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[36mPartner Load (2.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT `partners`.* FROM `partners` WHERE `partners`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered stats/_dashboard_block.html.erb (Duration: 1.5ms | Allocations: 287)
  Rendered stats/_dashboard_block.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 56)
  Rendered stats/_dashboard_block.html.erb (Duration: 6.1ms | Allocations: 465)
  Rendered stats/_dashboard_block.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 56)
  Rendered stats/_dashboard_block.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 47)
  Rendered stats/_dashboard_block.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 55)
  Rendered stats/_dashboard_block.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 46)
  Rendered stats/_dashboard_block.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 45)
  Rendered dashboards/_system.html.erb (Duration: 13.9ms | Allocations: 2478)
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 21.4ms | Allocations: 3065)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 33.8ms | Allocations: 4938)
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[36mTracker Create (6.4ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO `trackers` (`request_id`, `session_identifier`, `session_id`, `started_at`, `ended_at`, `user_agent`, `ip_address`, `host`, `controller`, `action`, `status`, `partner_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ()[0m
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (15.5ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
Completed 500 Internal Server 

I tried removing arguments but stylesheet_link_tag is not even taking a single argument.
```

Comment: Please share the error message, including the stack trace, from the application's log file.

Comment: What is the code at this line? `app/controllers/application_controller.rb:93:in `track'`

Comment: Added the track method.

Comment: Rollbar is just  a ruby gem for error logging. Eventually it will give me error whether I have it in development mode or not.

Comment: that `resolve` method had 2 arguments before sprockets v4, maybe keep it at v3 while updating.